# VirtualBox Linux Mint Refuses to Save to Hard Disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, linux-mint

Every time I start up Linux Mint and add some files to the Desktop, they disappear when I shut down and restart the OS. I could just save the state of the machine every time, but that's a bit annoying. How do I make hard disk changes save?

Update: Okay now I'm basically using Linux Ubuntu to do all my stuff, and that does work for some reason, but I would really prefer to get Linux Mint running if possible!

Comment: are you booting from the live CD or have you installed Mint?

Comment: it looks like he is using mint in VIRTUALBOX, not as a stand alone OS, then again, I am not very familiar with virtualbox, so your question may still have significance.